# WSO2 ESB SOAP headers lost

Tags: wso2, soapheader, wso2-esb

I'm trying to forward a simple web service call through ESB, however Send mediator removes all  headers from SOAP message.

Source message:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/TestService/SendMessage</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:51d31061-2eab-41cf-b073-3dbee322e0e1</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
        <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://if-golubets-dn:8000/test</a:To>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <SendMessage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <message>Test</message>
    </SendMessage>
</s:Body>
```

Message after Send:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header />
<s:Body>
    <SendMessage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <message>Test</message>
    </SendMessage>
</s:Body>
```

How can I preserve the Action header? I tried header mediator, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer:

```
<property name="PRESERVE_WS_ADDRESSING" value="true"/>
```